# How can I add PostgreSQL to an existing Entity Framework 6 project while keeping the existing SQL Server provider intact?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

Disclaimer: I'm a junior dev and still trying to wrap my head around EF6.

Our team has a .NET Framework 4.7 / Entity Framework 6 project which relies on MS SQL Server for its data. We just upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 but it seems like some of the recommended tools don't work on VS2022. We use database first for EF.

Recently, our team decided to add a create a new PostgreSQL database and we need to add support for it in our existing project.

I've installed the following packages:

- Npgsql
- EntityFramework6.Npgsql

I was advised to also install the following VS extension:

- Npgsql PostgreSQL Integration

But it seems like it is only compatible up to VS2019 and has been abandoned.

In order to test if I could even set this up at all with the recommended VS extension, I used Visual Studio 2019 instead of 2022.

After installing the items listed above, my web.config file now has this entityFramework config:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

and this system.data config:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

At this point, I attempted creating a new `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`, I was able to choose the table and procedure I wanted.

This is where I got stuck.

A new connectionString was added to my web.config, alongside the encrypted connectionString we were already using for SQL Server. When testing, it throws an exception saying that I cannot have an unencrypted connectionString next to an encrypted connectionString.

I tried placing the connectionString within the code but then it throws errors when parsing the connectionString, saying that it does not recognize the parameters. I used the same parameters from the connectionString that was automatically generated.

So, it seems like it's reading the Postgres connectionString with the SQL Server provider instead of the PostgreSQL provider.

Any suggestions? Or resources I can use to help me along the way? Thanks in advance.